# Converting C code to x86-64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I'm trying to convert my C code to x86-64. My goal is to reverse a linked list. The two parameters that are passed in are the head ptr and the offset to to get the address of the pointer field (i.e. the pointer to the next node in the list).

From what I understand, the head ptr is passed in through the rdi register, and the offset is passed in through the rsi register. I keep getting a segmentation fault when it reaches the line "mov rcx, [rbx]." The segmentation fault goes away when it's just "mov rcx, rbx" and the line following is changed from "mov [rbx], rdx" to "mov rbx, rdx." However, I end up in an infinite loop because it keeps simply assigning the same values over and over again.

When I'm following along with my C code, all of the logic in the x86-64 makes sense to me, so I'm really at a standstill. Any ideas? This is my first time using x86-64.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.text
.global reverse_asm_64

reverse_asm_64:
push rbx
push r12

mov rax, 0x0
#headptr
mov rbx, rax
#nextptr
mov rcx, rax
#new_headptr
mov rdx, rax
#head
mov rax, [rdi]

#checks if head is null
cmp rax, 0
je null_ret

#move offset into a register
mov r12, rsi
add rax, r12
#add offset to rax to get the next ptr
mov rbx, rax

while_start:

#checks that next ptr isn't null
cmp rbx, 0x0
je while_done

#setting the next ptr
mov rcx, [rbx]

# *headptr = new_headptr
mov [rbx], rdx

#new_headptr = headptr
mov rdx, rbx

#sets headptr to nextptr
mov rbx, rcx

jmp while_start

while_done:
mov rax, rdx
sub rax, rsi

null_ret:
pop r12
pop rbx
ret
```

Comment: Is there a good reason for such a seemingly useless exercise?

Comment: There are tools that are really good for this: C compilers.  Many of them have options to emit assembly code, and those that don't can be paired with disassemblers.

Comment: Glad someone agrees that this is a useless exercise. I need to get it done for a class assignment, but I've been stuck the past few days.

Comment: You didn't post your C code, but the first integer/pointer arg is passed in `rdi`, and the second in `rsi`.  What is "offset"?  A position into the linked list?  Your asm is hard to read; indent your instructions more than the labels.  Also, comments on the same line as the instructions make things more compact.

Comment: Also, you don't need to save/restore rbx and r12.  You can use r8, r9, r10 and r11 as scratch regs, along with rax/rcx/rdx/rsi/rdi.

Comment: Anyway, use a debugger to single-step your code and look at register values to make sure they match what you expect.  See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for gdb tips.

Comment: I believe that John and Eugene's point was that it's "useless" to write this in assembler since C is likely to do a much better job. However, I wouldn't describe it as a "useless exercise" if the goal is to learn how to write assembler. It takes a concept programmers probably already know (linked lists) and performs a common and easily understood operation on it (reversing the list). This allows the newbie assembler student to use looping, comparing, offsets, reading input parameters, returning values, etc. As an intro to assembler exercise, I've seen much worse. You'd prefer something harder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reluctant to just post the re-worked code I created as part of writing this answer.  You aren't going to learn anything that way.

So, here are some things you might want to fix to start:

1) Given that linux has ~7 registers you can use for scratch, there doesn't seem to be a need to push/pop rbx and r12.  Use other registers that don't need to be saved.

2) It looks like you are putting the comments *after* the code they describe (`#headptr` et al).  This is *not* what people who read your code are going to expect.  Most common is either to put it on the line before, or (especially in assembler) on the same line.

3) It is common practice in C to always zero out all the variables (especially pointers) before you use them.  However, less so in asm.  Especially when the next statement is going to assign a different value to that same register.  This isn't a problem in C since the compiler's optimizers will simply discard the redundant initializer.  But assembler doesn't have optimizers, so this is just a waste of space/cycles.  Only zero things that must be zeroed.

4) When zeroing a register, use `xor eax, eax` instead of `mov`.  It smaller/faster.

5) If your code is called with `head_ptr = reverse_asm_64(head_ptr, 16)`, you are going to want to check rdi to see if it is null before dereferencing it.

6) In asm, you should use `test rdi, rdi` to see if rdi is zero rather than `cmp rdi, 0`.  It's smaller/faster.

7) "move offset into a register" Say what?  The offset is already in a register: rsi.  Why make a copy in r12?

8) The very first time you "checks that next ptr isn't null", you have just added the offset to the value.  Unless your offset is zero, this isn't going to do what you intend.  See also #6.

9) The "add offset to rax to get the next ptr" is only done once (ie outside the loop).  Wouldn't each pointer in the list need to have this offset added?

There's more, but that's 9 items.  Seems like enough for a start.